# Clicking a different button inside each loop iteration

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I'm having troubles with clicking an item inside an each loop (in CasperJS) here's a small part of the code:

```
$("#id1",html).each(function( index ) {/*loop-start*/
    var job = {};/*init*/
    casperjs.click(".class2");
    boo.waitForSelector('selector3', function() {
        job.url = casperjs.getCurrentUrl();
        page.pagejobs.push(job);
        casperjs.back();

    casperjs.waitForSelector('selector4', function() {

    },function(){

    }, 6000);
  },function(){

  }, 10000);

});/*loop-end*/
```

Basically I'm clicking a button (`casper.click(".class2")`) that's fine no problem here. The first time it works fine 'cause it clicks the first button with the selector (.class2) but the problem is that there are many selectors with the same class than that one (They are children of (#id1)).

So its something like:

```
<div id="id1">
  <div class="anything">
     <a button class="class2"> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="anything">
      <a button class="class2"> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So this `casper.click(".class2")` is my problem I think. I need a way to select the current button on each iteration of the `each` function. Note that I can't use `$(this)`.

Comment: "Loop" in Spanish, apparently. (Neat translation extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Comment: Loop* my bad. I derped right there :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS selectors provide the [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class which you can use to select a child element based on an index. This works as expected when only `.anything` elements are children of `#selector1goeshere`.

You can use

```
casper.click("#id1 > :nth-child("+(index+1)+") > a.class2");
```

You can also use XPath expressions to do this which don't have that limitation of only having `.anything` children. For example like this:

```
var x = require("casper").selectXPath;
...
casper.click(x("//*[@id='id1']/*[contains(@class,'anything')]["+(index+1)+"]/a[contains(@class,'class2')]"));
```

Comment: ("+(index+1)+") THIS! is what i needed. I just couldn't find a way. Tyvm!